# how to fix the position of text from left to center in div using bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap-modal

My code is here below. I want to fix the content of

tag in between left and center. I have tried resolving the issue. I am able to fix it to the left. But it is not limited to the center, if we add more content it is going out of center.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div>
    <p class="position-fixed pull-left"><bold>Hello</bold><br/>This is to test the code and make sure that the and make sure that the code is working fine </p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Apple1</button><br/><br/>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Apple2</button><br/><br/>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Apple3</button><br/><br/>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Apple4</button><br/><br/>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The required output is here below.

```
         Welcome to my small webpage
Hello
This is to test the code              [button1]
and make sure that the                [button2]
code is working fine.                 [button3]
                                      [button4]
                                      [button5]
                                      [button6]
```

The output I am getting is here below.

```
         Welcome to my small webpage
Hello
This is to test the code and make sure that the and make sure that the                          
code is working fine.                                [button1]
                                            [button2][button4]
                                          [button3]        
                                                     [button5]
                                                     [button6]
```

Comment: width 100% to the parent and max-width 50% to the element you're trying to align from left to center

Answer (score 0):

You should check Bootstrap grid behavior, inside the container you'll need a row with three columns:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">Text list</div>
        <div class="col-4">Buttons list</div>
        <div class="col-4">[Empty]</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Last column will be empty or you add the class to the row `justify-content-start` so that the alignment will be to the left.

You'll need to write one tag `row` (inside same container) for each row you want to show.

Answer (score 0):

You need to invest some time on learning bootstrap grids in order to do what you want. For your solution I have this code below:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4"><p>Your paragraph goes here</p></div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">empty space between paragraph and buttons</div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">button 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">button 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">button 3 etc...</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You should also notice that `lg` in `col-` attribute, refers to large screen resolution. For medium, small and x-small resolutions (medium desktops, tablets, mobiles) you should use `col-md-` , `col-sm-` , `col-xs-` , etc. You can also use more than one column class in your `div` i.e. `class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6"` . First thing to do: Read all about Bootstrap grids.